# Bug in generating urls from a subdomains in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-2.3, symfony-routing

My project has a subdomain `shop.example.com` and `routing.yml` is using the host matching feature (requires Symfony >=2.2) as explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html):

```
example_shop:
    resource: "@MyShopBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    host:     "shop.example.com"

example_front:
    resource: "@MyFrontBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

URL **matching works just fine**, but I have some **trouble generating full/relative urls** (linking the domain to the subdomain e viceversa):

```
<pre>shop_index:  {{ url('shop_index') }}</pre>
<pre>shop_test:   {{ path('shop_test') }}</pre>
<pre>front_index: {{ url('front_index') }}</pre>
<pre>front_test:  {{ url('front_test') }}</pre>
```

When I run the above code from `index.html.twig` of `MyFrontBundle` (route `example.com`):

```
shop_index:  http://shop.example.com/app_dev.php/
shop_test:   //shop.example.com/app_dev.php/test
front_index: http://example.com/app_dev.php/
front_test:  http://example.com/app_dev.php/test
```

However the same code in `index.html.twig` of `MyShopBundle` (route `shop.example.com`) produces:

```
shop_index:  http://shop.example.com/app_dev.php/
shop_test:   /app_dev.php/test
front_index: http://shop.example.com/app_dev.php/     <!-- wrong! -->
front_test:  http://shop.example.com/app_dev.php/test <!-- wrong! -->
```

As you can see the problem is generating urls from the subdomain poiting to full or relative urls of the domain. How ca I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your front routes are not fixed to a domain like the shop routes, the `url` function uses the current domain, as every domain matches to this routes. Try to fix down your frontend routes:

```
example_front:
    resource: "@MyFrontBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    host:     "example.com"
```

Comment: Works perfect now! Thanks! Any chance to make domain dynamic? I'm using a fixed parameter "domain" in parameters.yml but I'd like to use a container one (server name). Can't find it...